# Double query error

Tags: mysql

I am having one small application which is used by some schools. I am trying the following Mysql Double query into the application. But its fetching some errors.

```
    mysql> select fname,(select fname,lname from id) as google from id;
    ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
    mysql>

mysql> select fname,(select fname from id) as google from id;
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
mysql>
```

I am trying to accomplish  which will display `ID , Fname , Lname` using Double Query.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to execute the above query which will display . ID , Fname ,Lname using Double Query

Comment: No need to add "Solved" in the title. Accept the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fetching two operand in query `select fname,lname from id` which needs to be 1 because you are using alias, if you want both fields, better not use alias.

Comment: mysql> select fname,(select fname from id) as google from id;
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
mysql>

Comment: select fname from id is returning 1+ result you need to restrict it to 1 or need to change your where clause.

Comment: Okay Query Got executed , But i am not able to fetch multiple columns .

Comment: You can repeat the statement one more time, if you stick to use subquery which is however not preferable select fname,(select fname from id limit1) as google,(select lname from id limit 1) as google_1 from id;

Comment: select id,(select fname from id where id=1) as google from id;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19921/discussion-between-ssk-and-vardan-gupta)

Comment: I need to wrap up my company work, will get back to you once done, thanks!

Comment: OKay Vardan , i will be waiting

Answer (score 3):

As vardan has mentioned you should fetch only one operand from your second query,
Also the result of that second query must be an rsingle record, in this case you are getting multiple records
try using `where` condition in your second query.

**EDIT**

Do one thing `SELECT id, fname, lname as google FROM id`